# pipe telnet output to logfile with tee command using Java process exec

Tags: java, linux, unix, pipe, telnet

Concurrency and stream reading in a [project](https://github.com/THUFIR/TelnetConsole) for a simple [MUD client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_client) is proving a bit of headache, so I'm trying to find an alternative.  The tee command looks to fit the bill for concurrently splitting output between a file and the terminal.  How do I then send messages through the telnet session?

Splitting remote output between the console and a file:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/TelnetConsole$ telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com 3000 | tee out.txt
Trying 38.102.137.140...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
```

How do I then pipe or somehow send Java messages to the system telnet client?  Or, perhaps, would it make more sense to use `exec` and start the telnet session, and tee, from within Java?  Just looking for a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exec sounds like a better solution since you want to control both input and outpud data. And do you really need tee in when you use exec, I don't understand why...

Also take a look at netcat instead of telnet - telnet has some special character handling that could give you trouble if you plan to send binary data.

Comment: it's for a mud, so telnet is preferred.  Just looking into how to write to the telnet session from exec. I can parse the log file which tee generates.  No threads, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

By no means functioning code, but definitely simpler than using Apache TelnetClient.  However, it's not possible to use the pipe command(?) with java exec:

```
package exec;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class Ideone {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Ideone().start();
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        String[] s = new String[6];
        s[0] = "telnet";
        s[1] = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
        s[2] = "3000";
        s[3] = "|";
        s[4] = "tee";
        s[5] = "out.log";
        for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++ ) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        read();
        write(stdout);
    }

    private void parseLog() {
        //read the log file, automate responses
    }

    private void write(InputStream stdin) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }

    private void read() {

        Thread read = new Thread() {

            String command = null;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader bufferedInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                do {
                    try {
                        command = bufferedInput.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    } finally {
                    }
                } while (true);
            }
        };
        read.start();
    }
}
```